# Is ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext) obsolete in MVC5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-5

I am upgrading a web site from MVC3 to MVC5. I simply used NuGet to install Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc version 5.2.3 and everything seemed to be working fine. But upon closer examination I noticed that this code was no longer running:

```
public abstract class BaseController : System.Web.Mvc.Controller
{
    protected override void Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        LogRequest();
        UpdateUserSession();
        base.Execute(requestContext);
    }
}
```

I found [this lifecycle documentation](https://www-asp.azureedge.net/v-2016-04-19-025/media/4773381/lifecycle-of-an-aspnet-mvc-5-application.pdf) (linked from [here](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/lifecycle-of-an-aspnet-mvc-5-application)) which seems to confirm that `Execute` is no longer called by MVC.

However, [this documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.execute(v=vs.118).aspx) is unclear, saying

> This method is an implementation of Execute. You typically do not have to override this method. Override Initialize or ExecuteCore instead.

I would expect it to say "This method is no longer called by the MVC framework as of version 5 (or maybe 4)." Perhaps even mark it `[Obsolete]`, although there may have been good reasons not to do that.

Furthermore, my testing shows that `ExecuteCore` does not get called either! It looks like `OnActionExecuting` is the best place to move the code that used to live in `Execute`, is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it helps to anybody:

Old version:

```
errorManagerController.Execute(requestContext);
```

New version:

```
Response.RedirectToRoute(routeData.Values);
```